# Java 8 parallel stream reduction - thread count vs speedup

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, java-8, reduction

I am running an experiment on varying thread count for java 8 parallel stream's reduction operation: summation over 11.5 million numbers. I run it on 8 core intel xeon processor. I do not see much variation in the total execution time and total CPU time, when I vary the number of threads from 16 to 1. I **do get speed-up** over sequential version which uses 'streams' instead of `parallel streams'. I want to understand the correlation between no of threads and the speed-up over sequential reduction.

Can somebody help me with the reasoning for this please? Is my code incorrect somewhere?

Source code is [here](https://github.com/yogirjoshi/monitortools/blob/master/src/main/java/rithm/driver/Hypothesis2.java), line 74 performs parallel reduction.

Relevant part of the code is pasted below as well:

```
class RedOperator implements BinaryOperator<MonResult>{

    @Override
    public MonResult apply(MonResult t, MonResult u) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(t != null && u != null)
            t.count = t.count + u.count;
        return t;
    }

}

class FOFinisher implements Function<ConcurrentHashMap<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<MonResult>>, ArrayList<MonResult>>{


    protected MonResult id;
    protected boolean isParallel;
    public FOFinisher(boolean isparallel){
        id = new MonResult();
        id.count = 0;
        this.isParallel = isparallel;
    }
    public long getJVMCpuTime() {
        long lastProcessCpuTime = 0;
        try {
            if (ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean() instanceof OperatingSystemMXBean) {
                lastProcessCpuTime=((com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean)ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean()).getProcessCpuTime();
            }
        }
        catch (  ClassCastException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }finally{
            return lastProcessCpuTime;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public ArrayList<MonResult> apply(ConcurrentHashMap<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<MonResult>> t) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        long beg = System.nanoTime();
        long begCPU = getJVMCpuTime();
        ArrayList<MonResult> ret;
        RedOperator x = new RedOperator();
        if(isParallel){
            ret = new ArrayList<MonResult>(t.values().stream().map((alist)->{
                        return alist.parallelStream().reduce(id,x);
                    }).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }
        else{
            ret = new ArrayList<MonResult>(t.values().stream().map((alist)->{
                        return alist.stream().reduce(id,x);
                    }).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }

        long end = System.nanoTime();
        long endCPU = getJVMCpuTime();
        System.out.println("Exec Time:" + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert((end-beg),TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS));
        System.out.println("CPU Time : " + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert((endCPU-begCPU),TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS));
        return ret;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post pertinent code in the question, do not link. Links die, so the question loses all context.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/3788176

Comment: If you managed to produce a self-contained example to post here, which I could run to confirm your finding, then I (and others) would be able to help you.

Comment: Have you tried to parallelize the outer stream (`t.values().parallelStream()`) instead? Also it would be more efficient to use `ret = t.values().<...>.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));` instead of `new ArrayList<>(t.values()...collect(Collectors.toList())`.

Answer (score 2):

You do not see any speed-up comparing to sequential version because most of time is spent on splitting and joining tasks. In shortcut - the problem which you took under test is too simple. Please have a look at [Angelika Langer's Geecon presentation](http://presentations2015.s3.amazonaws.com/35_presentation.pdf) for more details.